# Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"); in Unity does not work for space key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I know this question has been asked and answered before but in my case, the answers just won't cut it. No answer I have looked at before was able to solve this and even in the Unity forum, I couldn't find useful information.
In Unity, I'm trying to build a 2D game, nothing big.

I am trying to set up my movement-script and horizontal movement worked like a charm. But jumping does not work, at least when the button is assigned to <kbd>Space</kbd>. Here is my code so far:

```cs
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
        Debug.Log("Jump!");
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
    }
}
```

It is -as you can tell- really simple. I tried to assign another key to `Jump`. With the <kbd>E</kbd> button everything went fine and my character jumped. But when using the <kbd>Space</kbd>, it did not work. Here's an image of my input manager:

[image: Picture of input manager]

Notice that I don't have a second Jump option configured. This was where I used the <kbd>E</kbd> key.

---

(I am using Linux Mint Tricia 19.3 if that gives any further information)

Comment: There was a similar question asked not so long ago. Apparently using space for input is broken on Linux. If you aren't using Linux, then please ignore this. If you are, I'll try to find the link to the original question.

Comment: yes, i am currently using linux mint tricia 19.3. thank you

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649028/unity-input-getkeydownkeycode-space-not-detecting-key-press)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))` maybe the issue is how the Jump button is set up, but nothing stands out to me.

Comment: this does not work for me... :( thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `GetKeyDown` and `KeyCode` to solve your problem. Your code can be modified to use these functions. I have improved your code down below. Just make  sure that `KeyCode.Space` is not assigned to any other key.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        Debug.Log("Jump!");
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
    }
}
```

I also have some scripting docs for you:

- KeyCode: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html
- GetKey: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Comment: If this suggestion worked, please accept this answer as it could help the community at large. If this answer does not work, please tell me via the comments as I may be able to help you.