Keystroke inputs from keyboard is not recognized/picked up by Unity
I am new to Unity Game development and started with some tutorials. I am facing a problem where keystroke inputs from keyboard is not recognized/picked up by unity. I checked some solutions online but am more confused request help.
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Space key pressed");
        myRigidbody.linearVelocity = Vector2.up * FlapStrength;
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("Key Stroke Not Received");
}

Debug:
Key Stroke Not Received
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Flappy_Bird:Update () (at Assets/Flappy_Bird.cs:22)

Key Stroke Not Received
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Flappy_Bird:Update () (at Assets/Flappy_Bird.cs:22)

Key Stroke Not Received
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Flappy_Bird:Update () (at Assets/Flappy_Bird.cs:22)

Key Stroke Not Received
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Flappy_Bird:Update () (at Assets/Flappy_Bird.cs:22)

I tried to check settings in Input Manager and also reinstalling Unity. Checked for solution here, but didn't find one which can solve this problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Update runs every frame, which can be dozens or hundreds of times a second, so unless you manage to press space every frame, you will see the else statement.  If you change GetKeyDown to GetKey then as long as you hold space you wont see the other log.

@hijinxbassist I searched for 'Space key pressed' in the console output but didn't find any. The script ran for 10 Secs, and I was pressing the spacebar frantically during this time.

@hijinxbassist I have never had an issue with checking for Input in Update and his code never even registers the first frame of pressing it down (as per docs), which I think is the problem.
Also he is trying to make a "flappy bird" so you don't want continuous flapping as long as its pressed, that's the whole point of difficulty, to do it enough times and keep the bird at a good height without losing and colliding.

@NPatch, thats right, trying to make flappy bird. Request you to kindly elaborate on what you mean by :
' ... and his code never even registers the first frame of pressing it down...'.

@Noob Does this happen only with Space or is the behaviour consistent with any key? Or if you switch it to GetKeyUp, is it still the issue?

Documentation on Input.GetKeyDown says "Returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key identified by name." Therefore the first frame when the keystroke is registered is the only one that will print "Space key pressed".

@NPatch, I checked with other keys, and also with GetKeyUp, as suggested. But still the same issue.
But the code segment is in void Update() class, so it shall initiate at every frame, which it is doing since it is printing the error message within else statement.

Does GetKey work at all? Because if this doesn't as well, you might have disabled the legacy InputSystem in your project.
If GetKey doesn't work, try Keyboard.current.space.wasPressedThisFrame instead of Input.GetKey*. If the latter works, then you are on the new InputSystem.

Are you sure you havent told unity to use the new input system?

@NPatch, I modified the code as:
void Update() {     if (Keyboard.current.escapeKey.wasPressedThisFrame == true)     {         Debug.Log("Space key pressed");         myRigidbody.linearVelocity = Vector2.up * FlapStrength;     }     else         Debug.Log("Key Stroke Not Received"); }
Same issue, the space bar or any other key input is not detected.

@BugFinder I just started my journey with Unity and C#, I have no idea how it is done. Still finding my way around.

To check this, go to Edit > Project Settings... > Player > Other Settings and Active Input Handling should be set to Input Manager (Old) (or Both might also work).  If you actually want to use the Input System package, you have to install it.  I would expect a different error if you had it selected but not installed, but worth a try.  credit to original author, I found this here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649028/unity-input-getkeydownkeycode-space-not-detecting-key-press

Remove the else statement and redo it. Do you see any messages? Somehow 4 debug.logs for "frantically pressing space" seem too few.

@Kevin, Active Input Handling is set to 'Both'. when I change it to Input Manager (Old), it restarts and pops the following warning: _This project is using the new input system package but the native platform backends for the new input system are not enabled in the player settings. This means that no input from native devices will come through.
Do you want to enable the backends? Doing so will RESTART the editor._
clicking yes and when re-checking the Active Input Handling, it is still set to both.

Just skip the else in general .. flooding the debug log is bad for performance as well even in a built application! If you wanted this to be true as long as the key is pressed use GetKey instead .. GetKeyDown is only true in exactly one frame per key press

@NPatch, removed else statement. No message. Modified the code further to check if the function is called :
 Debug.Log("Function Initiating"); if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true) {          Debug.Log("Space key pressed");          myRigidbody.linearVelocity = Vector2.up * FlapStrength;      }      else          Debug.Log("Key Stroke Not Received");
Output:
_ Function Initiating
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Flappy_Bird:Update () (at Assets/Flappy_Bird.cs:18)
Key Stroke Not Received
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
Flappy_Bird:Update () (at Assets/Flappy_Bird.cs:25)_

@derHugo I intended to check whether the function is even running or not. Using GetKey is not exactly what I would want since I am trying to build a flappy bird. I want it to move only when space is pressed. However, using the above code, I am still facing the same issue.
I am out of my wits here!

Still, as @derHugo also says, you don't need the else. So long as you're not seeing the message within the if statement, it's not registering a press. The absence of the message is enough and you're not littering your console log.

Have you messed with Time Scale in the Time settings perhaps?

well GetKey will work while the space bar is down, not just the 1 frame it went down, so make it like a thruster control.  However, i dont see you answering if any of those messages are showing in your console log,

Make sure that the game window has focus while running.
Clicking into the inspector or elsewhere in the editor will prevent the game window from capturing the input.
Click inside of the game window after pressing play to ensure it has focus.
It would also help your cause to completely remove the else statement, as to not flood the console with pointless logs.  It can be next to impossible to find a single message among thousands of messages.  The else statement log doesn't tell you anything anyway, only the if statement log is relevant.
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  
    {
        Debug.Log($"Space Pressed!");
    }
}


and everyone else who took the time to help me out. I made a fresh install of Unity today. I made sure to not mess up any settings this time. And now the code is working.
